# How to design a php page theme template in wordpress using either html or css?

Tags: wordpress

```
        <?php
        /*
        Template Name: isbn 
        */
        ?>

        <form action="" method="post" name="myForm">
        Filter <input id="isbn" type="text" name="isbn" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></form>

        <?php get_header(); ?>
        <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
        global $wpdb;
         $table_name = "isbn";  // change this to your table name
         $field = $_POST['isbn']; // change this to your isbn field $_POST['ISBN'];
        $retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name where isbn = '".$field."'");
        foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data) {

        echo $retrieved_data->title; 
        // echo $retrieved_data->image;  // for image
         }
        }
       ?>
```

This is a search form which i want to design. I have created this form in a page template named isbn. But when i am opening that page for editing i am unable to do this. I am using divi theme in wordpress.
So divi theme is not allowing me to edit this page. Due to which this page is looking very bad in look wise. 
Can anyone help me for designing this page by giving their codes or simply by giving their suggestions?
I am facing one more problem whenever i am writing css code in above code i am not getting anything. So i am totally blank that how to deal with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a WordPress page and add shortcode which you added in functions.php before. Don't create template for this page just use your shortcode only.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to create a page using divi theme,  then create shortcode for this form in functions.php and then use this shortcode in your page.

Comment: actuallly this page template is in themes folder. so how to create shortcode for this form?

Comment: You don't, have to create a template for this, just create shortcode and use in your page, I hope you understand my point

Comment: actuallly this page template is in themes folder. so how to create shortcode for this form?

Comment: //[foobar]
function foobar_func( $atts ){
 return "foo and bar";
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );

Comment: by creating shortcode u mean to say by using insertphp plugin? coz i am unable to use php directly in any wordpress page

Comment: Add this code in functions.php and use [foobar] in your WordPress page

Comment: if you don't mine may i have your email for further queries?

Comment: Itssurajchand@gmail.com

Comment: i have mailed you... please check your email

Answer (score 0):

you are inserting the `form` *above*  the  `get_header();` function, so it will be *outside* of the `html` tag and *outside* of the `body` tag. Move it into the `body`, then it should at least appear on the page, and you'll see what you need to do next.

Comment: so you mean to say that after  <?php get_header(); ?> i need to post my form tag and my css code?